# Table Value Functions and Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a Table Value Function. This function will have 3 arguments. Each of the returned table columns will get populated by a SELECT statement. Each SELECT statement will use one of the function parameters in its WHERE clause.

Here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getChangeTypes(@add_name varchar(20),@change_name varchar(20), @remove_name varchar(20))
RETURNS @changeTypes TABLE (
  addd      varchar(20),
  change   varchar(20),
  remove   varchar(20)
) 
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE @changeTypes
  SET addd = CAST ((SELECT change_type_id FROM db_comp_change_types WHERE     change_type_name = ''+@add_name+'') AS varchar(20)) 

UPDATE @changeTypes
SET change = CAST ((SELECT change_type_id FROM db_comp_change_types WHERE   change_type_name = ''+@change_name+'') AS varchar(20))  

UPDATE @changeTypes
SET remove = CAST ((SELECT change_type_id FROM db_comp_change_types WHERE  change_type_name = ''+@remove_name+'') AS varchar(20))  

 RETURN;
END;
GO
```

And here is the call to the function:

```
select * from getChangeTypes('Added Column Size','Changed Column Size','Removed Column Size')
```

I realize that the WHERE is not working correctly because of the way I am using the function parameters. Can someone suggest a way I can correctly incorporate the function parameters into the WHERE clause?

Many Thanks.

Comment: You need to first `INSERT` a record before you `UPDATE` it.

Answer (score 0):

You mus not update `@changeTypes` but you will have to insert into it

possibly like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getChangeTypes(@add_name varchar(20),@change_name varchar(20), @remove_name varchar(20))
RETURNS @changeTypes TABLE (
  addd      varchar(20),
  change   varchar(20),
  remove   varchar(20)
) 
AS
BEGIN

insert into @changeTypes(addd,change,remove) values(null,null,null)

UPDATE @changeTypes
  SET addd = CAST ((SELECT change_type_id FROM db_comp_change_types WHERE     change_type_name = ''+@add_name+'') AS varchar(20)) 

UPDATE @changeTypes
SET change = CAST ((SELECT change_type_id FROM db_comp_change_types WHERE   change_type_name = ''+@change_name+'') AS varchar(20))  

UPDATE @changeTypes
SET remove = CAST ((SELECT change_type_id FROM db_comp_change_types WHERE  change_type_name = ''+@remove_name+'') AS varchar(20))  

 RETURN;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Ok, your suggestion worked. But I don't understand the syntax of {''+@add_name+''} why wouldn't {''@add_name''} work? Why the + signs?

Answer (score 0):

Tf there are multiple values in the subquery, then this will throw an error

```
    CREATE FUNCTION getChangeTypes(@add_name varchar(20),@change_name varchar(20), @remove_name varchar(20))
RETURNS @changeTypes TABLE (
  addd      varchar(20),
  change   varchar(20),
  remove   varchar(20)
) 
AS
BEGIN

declare @db_comp_change_types Table (change_type_id int, change_type_name varchar(100))
Insert Into @db_comp_change_types 
Select 1, 'Add' UNION
Select 2, 'Add' UNION
Select 3, 'Remove' UNION
Select 4, 'Change'

insert into @changeTypes
(addd,change,remove) 
values(null,null,null)

UPDATE @changeTypes
  SET addd = CAST ((SELECT TOP 1 change_type_id FROM @db_comp_change_types  WHERE     change_type_name = @add_name) AS varchar(20)) 

UPDATE @changeTypes
SET change = CAST ((SELECT TOP 1 change_type_id FROM @db_comp_change_types  WHERE   change_type_name = @change_name) AS varchar(20))  

UPDATE @changeTypes
SET remove = CAST ((SELECT TOP 1 change_type_id FROM @db_comp_change_types  WHERE  change_type_name = @remove_name) AS varchar(20))  

 RETURN;
END
GO
```

I have just replaced the table with a Table variable. Hope this will help.